# Increase max file upload size in Wordpress hosted in Azure VM

Tags: wordpress, azure, virtual-machine

After being fed up with Godaddy hosting, I am trying to migrate my site to Azure VM. I am stuck at `maximum file upload size limit` which is fixed at 40 MB, while my site backup file is around 850 MB.
Adding below lines in `.htaccess` file through `WP File Manager` didn't work. No luck with restarting VM too.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Is there some workaround to increase size of file upload? How do I see site files? I feel CPanel's File Manager was pretty good and straight forward.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this one as it is more a word press issue and not related to the Azure VM, but thought I would share I moved from GoDaddy to Wordpress for hosting. Wordpress actually does a great job hosting my personal site. Just thought I would share :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uploading `.user.ini` file with below content to `htdocs`folder fixed the issue. Make sure to use `Advanced File manager` plugin to upload the file. Other Wordpress file managers don't allow files that start with `dot`.

```
memory_limit=256M
upload_max_filesize=1024M
post_max_size=1024M
max_execution_time=300
max_input_time=300
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still reading this.  The default Azure WebApp allows 8MB upload.  To increase to 64MB, I did the following.

In .user.ini in /site/wwwroot I added.

```
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 76M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

In web-config.php I added.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
```

I am using Project Nami WordPress on an IIS server so I had to do add the following to web.config.

```
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="67108864"/>
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

Then rebooted the web app in the Azure portal.

Comment: Perhaps not unsurprisingly my stock Azure WP app service needed both @Green goblin's .user.ini and also this web.config modification to work. However with both it worked a treat.

I just downloaded the Azure publish profile which includes FTP details and made both mods that way.

The <security> stuff goes directly under the <system.webserver> web.config tag, to save anyone looking that up.